# Connection Cast Exception Wildfly

Tags: wildfly, postgresql-9.3

I am using Wildfly8 and postgresql as my DB. I need org.postgresql.PGConnection in order to implement LISTEN/NOTIFY functionality of postgresql.

My code looks like:

```
private Connection conn;
private org.postgresql.PGConnection pgconn;
Conn = entityManager.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
this.pgconn = conn.unwrap(org.postgresql.PGConnection.class);
```

I get following Exception:

> `java.sql.SQLException: Not a wrapper for: org.postgresql.PGConnection`

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Upon printing the value of Conn, i get: :org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7@610ce5b

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that in this case your first instance of Connection is a Proxy Object. If you are using Wildfly you must do this:

```
((WrappedConnection)conn).getUnderlyingConnection().unwrap(PgConnection.class);
```

Also you must declare in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" />
            <module name="org.postgresql" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```